# JavaScript scoping with index search

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a large array of users which are comprised of 3 different user types (`"Admin"`, `"Moderator"`, `"User"`). Each user will have the following properties: (`"name"`, `"companyId"`, `"type"`).

The first method `function orchestrateUsers(users)`(which I have managed to code) will take 1 parameter: an array of users and must return a grouped list according to the user property "type".

The second method will take 4 parameters: a grouped list (result from the first method), an array of user types to include in the search, a string representing the user property to filter by and a string representing the value of the user property. This method must return an array of users as per the search parameters.

I need help with the second method.

```js
const users = [{
  "name": "Joe",
  "companyId": "A2100",
  "type": "Admin"
}, {
  "name": "Jane",
  "companyId": "A2100",
  "type": "Moderator"
}, {
  "name": "Smith",
  "companyId": "A2100",
  "type": "User"
}, {
  "name": "Smith",
  "companyId": "A2100",
  "type": "User"
}, {
  "name": "Rocket",
  "companyId": "A3100",
  "type": "Admin"
}, {
  "name": "Rick",
  "companyId": "A3100",
  "type": "User"
}, {
  "name": "Tim",
  "companyId": "A4100",
  "type": "Admin"
}]

function orchestrateUsers(users) {
  let result = {};

  users.forEach(user => {
    if (result[user.type]) result[user.type].push(user.name);
    else result[user.type] = [user.name];
  });
  return result;
}
console.log(orchestrateUsers(users));

//second method
function searchUsers(orchestratedUsers, userTypes, property, value) {
  //need help here
  userTypes.forEach(userType => {
    if (userTypes.find(userType => userType === "User")) {
      console.log(userType);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: You should have edited your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48525442/1048572) instead of deleting it and asking a new one

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you need to group the users for the second version and should be able to use `Array#filter`.

The filter only needs to check 2 conditions...that `type` is in the `userTypes` array and that the object property  matches  the input `value`.

Have set value match to compare lower case strings and used partial match

```js
const users = [{ "name": "Joe", "companyId": "A2100", "type": "Admin" }, { "name": "Jane", "companyId": "A2100", "type": "Moderator" }, { "name": "Smith", "companyId": "A2100", "type": "User" }, { "name": "Smith", "companyId": "A2100", "type": "User" }, { "name": "Rocket", "companyId": "A3100", "type": "Admin" }, { "name": "Rick", "companyId": "A3100", "type": "User" }, { "name": "Tim", "companyId": "A4100", "type": "Admin" } ]


function searchUsers(array, userTypes, property, value) {
   value = value.toLowerCase();// compare both in same case      
   return array
        .filter(o => userTypes.includes(o.type) && o[property].toLowerCase().includes(value))
}

// input variables
const userTypes = ['Admin','User'],
      prop = 'name',
      value = 'smit';// lowercase partial of "Smith"
      
const res = searchUsers(users, userTypes, prop , value )
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thanks! The question requires me to use the returned result from `function orchestrateUsers(users)` though. That's my predicament